# What is the most advantage using Saxon for .net?

Tags: .net, xslt, saxon

I'm working in .net 4.0 C# xslt1.0.
I hesitate to migrate with saxon processor is there real différencies in performance?

Comment: If you use Saxon, you may or may not have a performance gain(you can profile to find out), but the big advantage is that you have the option to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: What differences, between what?

Comment: speed performance between xslt1.0 and  2..0

Comment: Comparing "speed performance between xslt1.0 and 2..0" is like comparing speed performance between monkeys and men -- this is quite imprecise question. More specifically, you cannot compare speed performance on the features that only XSLT 2.0 has, and people usually choose XSLT 2.0 over XSLT 1.0 exactly for these new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any performance comparisons between Microsoft's XSLT 1.0 processor and the Saxon XSLT 2.0 processor on .NET.

I imagine you are talking about execution speed, but what is much more important is development speed: you can buy a decent server for about half the cost of hiring a programmer for a day. And in my experience (though it depends on the task) development productivity with XSLT 2.0 is about doubled compared with XSLT 1.0.